# Linker wrapping with --wrap option does not wraps symbols called by jmp instruction

Tags: c++, c, linux, linker

I am trying to do memory tracking system using the linkage wrapping of allocators and deallocators calls. I am using C++ 11 so here is the list of wraps that I have:

```
#define wrap(symbol) __wrap_ ## symbol

extern "C" {
void* wrap(malloc)(size_t size);
void* wrap(realloc)(void* ptr, size_t new_size);
void  wrap(free)(void *ptr);
void* wrap(calloc)(size_t num, size_t size);
char* wrap(strdup)(const char *str1);

// operator new(unsigned long)
void* wrap(_Znwm)(std::size_t count);

// operator new[](unsigned long)
void* wrap(_Znam)(std::size_t count);

// operator new(unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
void* wrap(_ZnwmRKSt9nothrow_t)(std::size_t count, const std::nothrow_t& tag);

// operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
void* wrap(_ZnamRKSt9nothrow_t)(std::size_t count, const std::nothrow_t& tag);

// operator delete(void*)
void wrap(_ZdlPv)(void *ptr);

// operator delete[](void*)
void wrap(_ZdaPv)(void *ptr);

// operator delete(void*, std::nothrow_t const&)
void wrap(_ZdlPvRKSt9nothrow_t)(void *ptr, std::nothrow_t const&);

// operator delete[](void*, std::nothrow_t const&)
void wrap(_ZdaPvRKSt9nothrow_t)(void *ptr, std::nothrow_t const&);

// placement operator delete
// operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
void wrap(_ZdlPvm)(void* ptr, unsigned long);

// operator delete[](void*, unsigned long)
void wrap(_ZdaPvm)(void* ptr, unsigned long);

} // extern "C"
```

The problem is I meet some calls to operators delete that are not calles by instruction call but using jmp instead in libstdc++ headers:

```
(gdb) disas std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_destroy
Dump of assembler code for function std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_destroy(unsigned long):
   0x00007ffff56b3d90 <+0>:     mov    rdi,QWORD PTR [rdi]
   0x00007ffff56b3d93 <+3>:     jmp    0x7ffff560c7d0 <_ZdlPv@plt>
End of assembler dump.
```

In this case it is a destructor of `std::string`. The same time call to the new in `std::basic_string::_M_create` was wrapped. I am not 100% sure about it, but most likely it is a string allocated as a buffer for `std::stringstream` in this case. I have the same issue with another `stringstream`s and std::strings as well and it could be fixed by passing an allocator for the template that can call a proper functions to allocate and deallocate but this solution is not an option for me for different reasons.

AFAIU this code is located in headers and get compiled with my project so the questions is:

1. How to turn this jump to operator delete definition in plt to a call?
2. Or how to force linker to wrap symbols called by jmp?

I am compiling with:

```
-Wl,--wrap=malloc,--wrap=realloc,--wrap=free,--wrap=calloc,--wrap=strdup,--wrap=_Znwm,--wrap=_Znam,--wrap=_ZnwmRKSt9nothrow_t,--wrap=_ZnamRKSt9nothrow_t,--wrap=_ZdlPv,--wrap=_ZdaPv,--wrap=_ZdlPvRKSt9nothrow_t,--wrap=_ZdaPvRKSt9nothrow_t,--wrap=_ZdlPvm,--wrap=_ZdaPvm
```

I have also blamed tail call optimization for it and tried to compile with `-fno-optimize-sibling-calls`. Doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You have spurious whitespace in `--wra    p=_Znam`

Comment: From where did you get the list of symbols? Could it be one of the unpronounceable _Zn* symbols is incorrect? Or did you perhaps miss an overload?

Comment: @yugr Nice catch. And another one in `--wrap=_ZdlPvRKSt9nothro    w_t`.

Comment: @yugr, bitmask, thanks, but it is just an issue of multiline copying. Any ideas on how to fix my issue?

Comment: @bitmask all this symbols is mangled versions of new/delete operators. I got the list of them at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new. I don't think that I miss something because as you can see I have call to simple delete unwrapped, for which I have provided the wrapper and specify it with --wrap option. I guess the main issue is that it got jumped to, not called..